# Error: Cannot find module './lib-cov/express'

Tags: node.js, express, browserify

I'm trying to npm start the following package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-jsx",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies" : {
    "express" : "~4.0.0",           
    "ejs" : "~0.8.5",               
    "mongoose" : "~3.8.1",          
    "passport" : "~0.1.17",         
    "passport-local" : "~0.1.6",    
    "passport-facebook" : "~1.0.2", 
    "passport-twitter" : "~1.0.2",  
    "passport-google-oauth" : "~0.1.5",
    "connect-flash" : "~0.1.1",     
    "bcrypt-nodejs" : "latest",
    "jquery": "latest",

    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "method-override": "~1.0.0",
    "express-session": "~1.0.0"     
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "latest",
    "envify": "^3.0.0",
    "reactify": "latest",
    "uglify-js": "~2.4.15",
    "watchify": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "watchify -o public/js/bundle.js -v -d .",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production browserify . | uglifyjs -cm > public/js/bundle.min.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "reactify",
      "envify"
    ]
  }
}
```

However I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module './lib-cov/express' from '/Users/user/Documents/jsx-node/node_modules/express'

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it and i have installed all modules without any error.
When do you get this error?

Comment: yea did npm install, everything installed fine

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify an entry point for browserify. If you specify `.` it will use the "main" from your package.json. So it now tries to browserify your express server.

Either provide a different entry point instead of `.` or declare a "browser" field in the package.json.

Refer to [the package.json section of the browserify documentation](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#packagejson) for more details.

Comment: Good point. Added a link to corresponding section in the browserify documentation.